# GSON JsonReader giving me values instead of names?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have to refactor some areas of my app to use the streaming API in Gson, but very quickly I'm running into a strange problem I'm not sure how to get around. The following constructor on my class receives a JsonReader and is supposed to loop through the properties of the object.  LogCat shows the name of the first property output, then an exception "Expected a name but was BOOLEAN".  I only asked for the name using reader.nextName().  What gives?

JSON Object:

```
{
"IsActive":true,
"LocationName":"Denver",
...
}
```

Class constructor:

```
public AppLocation(JsonReader reader){

        try {
            reader.beginObject();
            while(reader.hasNext()){
                final String pName = reader.nextName();
                final boolean isNull = reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL;
                if(!isNull){
                    Log.d("MENET", pName);
                }else{
                    reader.skipValue();
                }
            }
            reader.endObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("MENET", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The streaming method of using this reader works with "elements" i.e. names or values.

So after the first "element", which is a name, you would get a value.

Except your code is calling `reader.nextName()` which is why it says "Expected a name..."

---

There is a good example on the Android site under `JsonReader`:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html